# Render plot as window over time

Tags: matlab

I'm a MatLab newbie so apologies in advance ... Oddly, I didn't find much help online. I want to render a time series plot as a movie that will show a window over time. At a given moment it time, it shows the plot at that point in time along with a few seconds before and after.

I'm trying this code where things like data, sampRate etc have been previously defined:

```
index = (1:nSamples)/sampRate + startTimeSec;

figure('name',fileName);
title('Seismic');
plot(index,data,'r*');

writerObj = VideoWriter('c:\temp\movie.avi');
open(writerObj);

fig = figure('name',fileName);
title('Seismic');
window = 200; %samples
for i=1:nSamples
    first = max([i-window/2,1]);
    last = min([i+window/2,nSamples]);
    clf;
    plot(index(first:last),data(first:last),'r*');
    writeVideo(writerObj,getframe(fig));
end
close(writerObj);
```

It bombs on the writeVideo with the error

> Error using capturescreen
>
> The rectangle passed to getframe must be at least partially on screen
>
> Error in getframe (line 105)
>
> ```
> x=builtin('capturescreen', varargin{:});
> ```
>
> Error in PlotData (line 60)
>
> writeVideo(writerObj,getframe(fig));

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the clf command? The documentation for getframe reads "getframe returns a movie frame. The frame is a snapshot of the current axis." Your clf command gets rid of the axes from the figure, hence the error. Remove clf and it should work!

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.  Read the error message carefully.  It says the frame must be **partially** on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `figure` twice.  The first call is enough, so get rid of this statement:

```
fig = figure('name', fileName);
```

Also, get rid of the extraneous `clf` call because your plot contents are going to be changed at each iteration of the loop so there's no need to clear the current figure before you put something in it.  I suspect that your plot frame is in the background, and it needs to be shown as the current frame in focus before you write the frame to file.  As such, try putting the frame in focus, then call `writeVideo`.  In other words, use the following modified code.  Anywhere that I've changed, I've placed comments:

```
index = (1:nSamples)/sampRate + startTimeSec;

figure('name',fileName);
title('Seismic');
plot(index,data,'r*');

writerObj = VideoWriter('c:\temp\movie.avi');
open(writerObj);

%// Remove this
% fig = figure('name',fileName);
window = 200; %samples
for i=1:nSamples
    first = max([i-window/2,1]);
    last = min([i+window/2,nSamples]);
    %// Remove this as well
    % clf;
    figure(1); %// Put frame in focus
    plot(index(first:last),data(first:last),'r*');
    %// Put title here
    title('Seismic');

    %// Change.  Just using getframe by default
    %// will call the current frame in focus
    writeVideo(writerObj,getframe);
end
close(writerObj);
```